# JS: jQuery plugin is not working with newest jQuery version

Tags: javascript, jquery, version, transition, fade

I just found this tutorial on making an image cross fade transition with jquery.
The demo page works perfectly (jquery 1.2.3 used).
But when I apply the code to my site (jquery 10.1.0 embedded) it is not working...

When I embed the 1.2.3 version it works.

Anyone an idea whats wrong with the code?

here it comes:

```
// wrap as a jQuery plugin and pass jQuery in to our anoymous function
(function ($) {
    $.fn.cross = function (options) {
        return this.each(function (i) { 
            // cache the copy of jQuery(this) - the start image
            var $$ = $(this);

            // get the target from the backgroundImage + regexp
            var target = $$.css('backgroundImage').replace(/^url|[\(\)'"]/g, '');

            // nice long chain: wrap img element in span
            $$.wrap('<span style="position: relative;"></span>')
                // change selector to parent - i.e. newly created span
                .parent()
                // prepend a new image inside the span
                .prepend('<img>')
                // change the selector to the newly created image
                .find(':first-child')
                // set the image to the target
                .attr('src', target);

            // the CSS styling of the start image needs to be handled
            // differently for different browsers
            if ($.browser.msie || $.browser.mozilla) {
                $$.css({
                    'position' : 'absolute', 
                    'left' : 0,
                    'background' : '',
                    'top' : this.offsetTop
                });
            } else if ($.browser.opera && $.browser.version < 9.5) {
                // Browser sniffing is bad - however opera < 9.5 has a render bug 
                // so this is required to get around it we can't apply the 'top' : 0 
                // separately because Mozilla strips the style set originally somehow...                    
                $$.css({
                    'position' : 'absolute', 
                    'left' : 0,
                    'background' : '',
                    'top' : "0"
                });
            } else { // Safari
                $$.css({
                    'position' : 'absolute', 
                    'left' : 0,
                    'background' : ''
                });
            }

            // similar effect as single image technique, except using .animate 
            // which will handle the fading up from the right opacity for us
            $$.hover(function () {
                $$.stop().animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 250);
            }, function () {
                $$.stop().animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 250);
            });
        });
    };

})(jQuery);

// note that this uses the .bind('load') on the window object, rather than $(document).ready() 
// because .ready() fires before the images have loaded, but we need to fire *after* because
// our code relies on the dimensions of the images already in place.
$(window).bind('load', function () {
    $('img.fade').cross();
});
```

html is that:

```
<img class="fade" src="original.jpg" style="background: url(hover.jpg);" />
```

heres the link to the tutorial (dated 2008):
http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-cross-fade-transition/

Comment: It uses `$.browser`, which was deprecated and recently removed. You can use the jQuery Migrate plugin to see what else it's using that has been removed - http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.browser is not supported by new version of jQuery.